# Chemfig does not render when pgfornament is used

Tags: chemfig, pgfornament

Pretty much what the title says. The molecule is not rendered if I use the `pgfornament` package.

Code 1:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig, mhchem}

\begin{document}

\setdoublesep{3pt}
\chemfig{[:75]R-C(=[::+60]O)-[::-60]O-[::-60]C(=[::+60]O)-[::-60]R}
\hspace{3em}
\ce{H2 + O2 = 2 H2 O}

\end{document}
```

The figure I get is as below:

[image]

Code 2:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{chemfig, mhchem}

\begin{document}

\setdoublesep{3pt}
\chemfig{[:75]R-C(=[::+60]O)-[::-60]O-[::-60]C(=[::+60]O)-[::-60]R}
\hspace{3em}
\ce{H2 + O2 = 2 H2 O}

\end{document}
```

The figure I get is as shown:

[image]

I do not get any error messages when I compile. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: No problem here. Can you should your log-file?

Comment: I have put the log file here: https://pastebin.com/FtLfgtbS

Comment: You have a quite old local pgfornaments.sty in `/home/software/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/pgfornament`. What happens if you remove this folder?

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. I had installed it before pgfornaments was part of main TeXLive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by removing old local `.sty` file.